# How to keep my web application active while redeploying a war or wab in karaf?

Tags: web, karaf, deploying, wab

Currently i am working on a web project using GWT and i am using karaf as a container, i installed the karaf war feature and deployed my war successfully and it worked perfectly. But when  ever i recompile my GWT project and create a new war to deploy into karaf my web application goes offline while the new war is deploying, is there any way to keep my application active and serve requests while the new WAR is deploying?